# How do i insert an element in the linked list using a function?

Tags: c++, c, insert, linked-list

I am using the following code but its showing error : expected constructor, destructor or type conversion before * token.
Its showing the error in function prototype and the function declaration lines.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <conio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

node *insert(node *head);    // the compiler is showing error here

main()
{
  int dat;
  char x,ch;
  struct node_type
  {
    int data;
    node_type *next;
  };

  typedef struct node_type node;

  //   node *head;
  node *temp;

  // head= NULL;
  temp=NULL;
  printf("do u wanna enter a new node? \n");
  scanf("%c", &x);
  if (x=='y' or x=='Y')
  {

    temp=(node *)malloc(sizeof(node));
    printf("enter the data: \n");
    scanf("%d ", &dat);

    temp->data= dat;
    temp->next = NULL;
  }

  printf("do u want to insert another element?\n");
  scanf("%c ", &ch);
  if( ch=='y' or ch=='Y')
  {
    insert(*temp);
  }

  getch();

}

node *insert(node *temp)
{
  int dat;
  char ch;
  node *new;

  new=(node *)malloc(sizeof(node));

  printf("enter the data: ");
  scanf(" %d ", &dat);
  new->data=dat;
  new->next=temp;
  temp=new;

  printf("do u want to insert another element?\n");
  scanf("%c ", &ch);
  if (ch == 'y' or ch == 'Y')
  {
    insert(*temp);
  }
  else
    return temp;

}
```

what is the error and how do i rectify it?

Comment: It's `int main(void)` at least, please!

Comment: Where is "node" defined?  Have you included its header file?

Comment: You might like to fully quote the error message(s) you get.

Comment: Is there any particular reason you don't just use std::list?

Comment: This doesn't look like C++.

Comment: @user3340866 - `I am using the following code...`. Why? `#include <list> int main() { std::list<int> IntList; IntList.insert(IntList.begin(), 4); }` I just inserted an item into a linked list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, you can move the definition of `node_type` out of your main function, above the declaration of the `insert` function. The error is because node is unknown to the compiler at the point it first sees it. So have something like this at the top:

```
struct node_type
{
  int data;
  node_type *next;
};

typedef struct node_type node;

node* insert(node *head);
```

That should take care of the problem you asked about, but there are a few others you need to take care of as well:

1. You shouldn't be dereferencing the parameter when you call `insert`, since the function expects a pointer. So for example, you should have this instead:

   ```
   if ( ch=='y' or ch=='Y')
   {
      //insert(*temp);
      insert(temp);
   }
   ```
2. In `insert`, you have a `node*` named `new`, but `new` is actually a keyword that shouldn't actually be used to name a variable. You might rename it to something else and it might look like:

   ```
   // new above was replaced with newNode
   node *newNode;

   newNode=(node *)malloc(sizeof(node));

   printf("enter the data: ");
   scanf(" %d ", &dat);
   newNode->data=dat;
   newNode->next=temp;
   temp=new;
   ```

Hopefully, that should get you to a point where you can compile and test your program.

Comment: Yeah i got it. The primary reason was using new as variable name. The code is now working. i really appreciate your help.

Answer (score 1):

for C

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <conio.h>
#include <iso646.h>

typedef struct node_type {
    int data;
    struct node_type *next;
} node;

node *insert(node **head);

node *new_node(void){
    int dat;
    node *new=(node *)malloc(sizeof(node));

    printf("enter the data: ");
    scanf(" %d", &dat);
    new->data = dat;
    new->next = NULL;
    return new;
}

void print(node *np){
    while(np){
        printf("%d ", np->data);
        np = np->next;
    }
    printf("\n");
}

int main(){
    int dat;
    char ch;

    node *temp = NULL;

    printf("do u wanna enter a new node? \n");
    scanf("%c", &ch);
    if (ch=='y' or ch=='Y') {
        temp=new_node();
    }

    printf("do u want to insert another element?\n");
    scanf(" %c", &ch);
    if( ch=='y' or ch=='Y'){
        insert(&temp);
    }
    print(temp);
    getch();
    return 0;
}

node *insert(node **temp){
    int dat;
    char ch;
    node *new = new_node();

    new->next=*temp;
    *temp=new;

    printf("do u want to insert another element?\n");
    scanf(" %c", &ch);
    if (ch == 'y' or ch == 'Y'){
        insert(temp);
    }
    return *temp;
}
```